# What are the ANOVA's benefits over a normal linear model?

Tags: r, anova

I'm experimenting with R and found that an anova() needs an object of type lm. But why should I continue with an anova after this:

```
> x <- data.frame(rand=rnorm(100), factor=sample(c("A","B","C"),100,replace=TRUE))
> head(x)
        rand factor
1  0.9640502      B
2 -0.5038238      C
3 -1.5699734      A
4 -0.8422324      B
5  0.2489113      B
6 -1.4685439      A

> model <- lm(x$rand ~ x$factor))
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = x$rand ~ x$factor)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.74118 -0.89259  0.02904  0.59726  3.19762 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -0.1878     0.1845  -1.018    0.311
x$factorB    -0.1284     0.2689  -0.477    0.634
x$factorC     0.4246     0.2689   1.579    0.118

Residual standard error: 1.107 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.04345, Adjusted R-squared: 0.02372 
F-statistic: 2.203 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: 0.1160
```

This tells me everything I need, or does it not? I'm curious why you want to continue with an anova(model)

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555/why-is-anova-taught-used-as-if-it-is-a-different-research-methodology-compared

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's look at what you get when you actually use the anova() function (the numbers are different than in your example, since I don't know what seed you used for generating the random numbers, but the point remains the same):

```
> anova(model)

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: x$rand
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
x$factor   2   4.142  2.0708  1.8948 0.1559
Residuals 97 106.009  1.0929
```

The F-test for the factor is testing simultaneously $H_0: \beta_1 = \beta_2 = 0$, i.e., the hypothesis that the factor in general is not significant. A common strategy is to first test this omnibus hypothesis before digging down which of the levels of the factor are different from each other.

Also, you can use the anova() function for full versus reduced model tests. For example:

```
> x <- data.frame(rand=rnorm(100), factor=sample(c("A","B","C"),100,replace=TRUE), 
                  y1=rnorm(100), y2=rnorm(100))
> model1 <- lm(x$rand ~ x$factor + x$y1 + x$y2)
> model2 <- lm(x$rand ~ x$factor)
> anova(model2, model1)

Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: x$rand ~ x$factor
Model 2: x$rand ~ x$factor + x$y1 + x$y2
Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     97 105.06                           
2     95 104.92  2   0.13651 0.0618 0.9401
```

which is a comparison of the full model with the factor and two covariates (y1 and y2) and the reduced model, where we assume that the slopes of the two covariates are both simultaneously equal to zero.

Comment: (+1) Good response. I would add that these are often particular contrasts that are interesting in DoE as analyzed through ANOVAs, and that the default ones (as returned by `summary.aov(lm(...))` or `anova(lm(...))` are not of particular interest.

Comment: @chl: It's a good point.  Although, I think there is something to be said for actually constructing the contrasts for the hypotheses that you are interested in testing.  There is no fundamental distinction between ANOVA and regression.  Sometimes, ANOVA routines hide the hypotheses that are being tested.  At the same time, ANOVA procedures sometimes package things in exactly the way that you want to see the results.

Comment: Thank you sir :) So I would first look at the anova, if the factor made any difference at all, before I looked at the lm()-output to see _which_ factors made the difference? But doesn't the lm()-output already tell me if the different factors are significant (with the 1-3 stars behind them)?

Comment: Not quite. The output from lm() above tells you whether there is a significant difference between level A (the reference level) and levels B and C. It does not tell you whether levels B and C are significantly different from each other. Of course, you could make level B (or C) your reference (with the relevel() function), but suppose you have a factor with many levels. Checking all pairwise contrasts between levels will become tedious. Plus, you are conducting lots of tests. The alternative is to first inspect the omnibus test to check whether there is anything going on to begin with.

Comment: Ha! Thanks a lot. It seems like I didn't understand that lm() only tested the factors against the reference level.