# Negative binomial pairwise comparison in R

Tags: multiple-comparisons, negative-binomial-distribution

I have fitted a negative binomial regression model to my data, and the summary of this compares latency of 3 resources to that of burrows:

```
NegativeBinomalLatencyModel <- glm.nb(Latency_s ~ Resource, data = Cricket)

summary(NegativeBinomalLatencyModel)
Coefficients:
           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      4.9416     0.3055  16.178   <2e-16 ***
ResourceFemale   0.3292     0.4895   0.672    0.501    
ResourceFood     0.1878     0.4228   0.444    0.657    
ResourceNone    -0.2179     0.4231  -0.515    0.606
```

I was wondering how to produce a pairwise comparison of this, comparing each resource to all the other resources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it using the `emmeans` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html).

Then simply do:

```
m_means <- emmeans(NegativeBinomalLatencyModel, ~ Resource)
#TO GET PAIRWISE COMPARISONS WITH DIFFERENCES INDICATED AS LETTERS
cld(m_means, Letters = letters)
```

The `emmeans` package has a very good documentation (see link above).

**Edit to address OPs comments:**

If you want to plot the data, you can do it simply via the `emmip()` function (from the `emmeans` package). Have look at `?emmip` for details. Using your specific example a basic plot could be generated like this:

```
#BASIC PLOT
emmip(m_means, ~ Resource) 
#BASIC PLOT WITH CONFIDENCE LIMITS
emmip(m_means, ~ Resource, CIs=T) 
#BASIC PLOT WITH CONFIDENCE LIMITS ON THE RESPONSE SCALE
emmip(m_means, ~ Resource, CIs=T, type="response")
```

Another way of plotting can be achieved by simply using the `plot()` function. For that have a look at `?plot.emmGrid`.

If you want more control, you can store the output of `cld()` in an object such as this:

```
m_means_table <- cld(m_means, Letters = letters)
```

This can then be used in `ggplot2` for example:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(m_means_table, aes(x=Resource, y=emmean)) + geom_point() + 
       geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=emmean-SE, ymax=emmean+SE))
```

If you want upper and lower confidence limits, you can simply replace `emmean-SE` with `asymp.LCL` and `emmean+SE` with `asymp.UCL`, respectively (from the `m_means_table` object).

Also have a look at my answer on `poisson` and `glm.nb` models here:
[poisson glm to observe whether effects of artificial light on the number of bat passes in each location were significant](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325334/poisson-glm-to-observe-whether-effects-of-artificial-light-on-the-number-of-bat/325431#325431)

Comment: Thanks, I'm having some trouble interpreting the output. It looks like this

 Resource   emmean        SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL .group
4     None 4.723694 0.2927040 Inf  4.150004  5.297383      a
1   Burrow 4.941642 0.3054607 Inf  4.342951  5.540334      a
3     Food 5.129405 0.2922820 Inf  4.556543  5.702268      a
2   Female 5.270799 0.3825413 Inf  4.521032  6.020567      a

Is there a way to plot this?

Comment: @Harry I added some more detail. Have a look and see if this answers you questions.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: cld() doesn't appear to be part of emmeans any more, it was deprecated. They suggest using pwpp() or pwpm()